# Create rule to Set Default Value

Tags: commerce, rules

Here my query is that, I have created one field in product type "Time(Interval)" and another field created in Line item types "(Default Time)" field.
My requirement is when user saves a new commerce order, Product type (Time(Interval) field) value auto saves in Line item field (Default Time) value.
how we can do this, any idea.

Comment: Richa, can you please share what you tried and where you got stuck doing it with rules?

Comment: no i am using drupal7

Comment: i agree, ok i will with rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement hook_commerce_cart_product_add()
The product which user is adding to cart and the line item is available with in this hook. you can fetch the Time(Interval) field value from product and save it to line item.

```
 
function my_module_commerce_cart_product_add($order, $product, $quantity, $line_item) {
   $commerce_line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item->line_item_id);
   $product_time = $product->time_interval['und'][0]['value'];
   $line_item->default_time = $product_time;
   commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
}
```

Comment: i will try this

Comment: it is possible it's work when new commerce order because it work with add to cart

Comment: The question is about using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to get this to work. How does this answer help to do so?

Comment: btw this function work but i need when order place.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens "Don't use rules, do it this way because it's better, simpler and more performant" is a perfectly acceptable answer to "how do I do x with rules"

Comment: @Clive, waw, really? Thanks for teaching me about this. Does that mean that the opposite is true also then. E.g. to answer questions (about Views) like "Don't use Views, here is how you can use module X as an alternative because it's better, simpler and more performant".  BTW: you must know the value of "X" I have in mind ... (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of X).

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no, depends on context. Use your best judgement case-by-case. Certainly be ready to be able to prove that a method is **empirically** better, more performant, etc, even if you don't include all of that preamble in the answer itself unless prompted. It's easy to do that when you're going from generic module -> code, less so when you're going to another module because you would actually need to profile the results for that proof instead of being able to definitively say "this is definitely running less code, and nearer the api, so it's quicker". Generally speaking...

Comment: ...sensible alternatives that solve the same problem are useful @Pierre. We have a wide range of audience so a code solution might be great for some, maybe not so much for others. If there are alternateives that can also be suggested succinctly (and I can't stress "succinctly" enough), then it's good news for everyone if they're all listed

Comment: @Clive : ok, merci! 1 more question if I may: for any D8 question to get something to work in Rules, would you (yes or no) consider something like this "sensible" then: "You cannot do this with rules in D8 yet, it you want it badly, then you can perfectly do this with D7, using a rule that looks like so and so". Can't imagine you'd say "yes" (though I'd hope ...), so where to draw the line?

Comment: Probably more of a meta discussion @Pierre, feel free to post there and I'll chime in